# What are good practices for linking JavaFX controllers together?

Tags: java, javafx, controller, fxml

I am trying to build my first 'real' application with java using JavaFX. I'm using FXML to design the whole thing and so I decided to divide up some parts into different `.fxml` files and link those to different controllers. I'm using one `MainController` linked to `main.fxml`, and within `main.fxml` I call some other fxml files using `fx:include`. All includes have their own controller.

The issue is that the controllers don't operate 100% independently, sometimes you want to press a button linked to one controller and have that so something to another controller. I have a solution that works, but I'm not sure if it is the best way to do it.

My solution is this: Have one abstract `SubController` class, which has protected static fields for each of the subcontrollers. Upon initialization `MainController` fills all of these fields with the controller classes it gets from `main.fxml`, as well as one field for `MainController` itself. Each of the sub-controllers inherit from `SubController` so that they can access the static fields and call the public methods of the other controllers.

```java
public abstract class SubController implements Initializable {

    protected static MainController mainController;
    protected static MenuBarController menuBarController;
    protected static VideoPanelController videoPanelController;

    public static void setMainController(MainController mainController) {
        SubController.mainController = mainController;
    }

    public static void setMenuBarController(MenuBarController menuBarController) {
        SubController.menuBarController = menuBarController;
    }

    public static void setVideoPanelController(VideoPanelController videoPanelController) {
        SubController.videoPanelController = videoPanelController;
    }
}
```

```java
public class MainController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private MenuBarController menuBarController;
    @FXML private VideoPanelController videoPanelController;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        SubController.setMainController(this);
        SubController.setMenuBarController(menuBarController);
        SubController.setVideoPanelController(videoPanelController);

    }
```

This way when a button is clicked in the menu bar, it can use a public method of the video panel controller:

```java
public class MenuBarController extends SubController {

    public void openVideo() {
        File selectedFile = chooseFiles(VIDEO_EXTENSIONS);
        if (selectedFile == null) return;
        videoPanelController.loadVideo(selectedFile);
    }

}
```

This works quite well, but I still feel like there's probably an easier way to do it. Is this a good way to go about it and if not, how else should I do it?

Comment: Use call back functions. `MenuBarController` would have a `Consumer<File> openVideoConsumer;`, and when a selected file is found, it will invoke the consumer & pass it the file: `openVideoConsumer.accept(selectedFile);`. Your `MainController` would wire the video panel to the menu: `menuBarController.setOpenVideoConsumer(videoPanelController::loadVideo);`. This way `MenuBarController` doesn't have to know of `VideoPanelController`, in the case you may want to change the menu to remove that option.

Comment: It's generally not good practice for controllers to communicate with each other at all. Use a MVC approach instead, where each controller communicates with a single model instance. See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx/32343342#32343342. Using a dependency-injection framework can simplify the process of giving the controllers access to the model.

Comment: Another alternative is to use an event bus. If you're using Spring Framework, it already has one integrated. Otherwise, you could use something like [EventBus from Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/EventBusExplained).

Comment: @James_D Thanks, I'll try to apply MVC to my program, that link was very useful to me. One last thing, using MVC, how should a Controller request to close the primary stage? I could store the primary stage in the model, but I feel like doing that kinda goes against the whole point of MVC, then the Model and the View aren't really separate entities anymore.

Comment: From any component (e.g. a `Button` or some kind of `Pane`) you can call `getScene().getWindow().hide()`.